# Temperature measurement into USB

Tags: usb, sensor, usb-device, input, thermistor

I am trying to get a couple of temperatures into my computer. In my little lab I have about 50 thermistors that look a bit like this [NTC-Thermistor](http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/557274/NTC-Thermistor-TTS1A103F34D3RY-40-100-C-Gehaeuseart-Radial-harzbeschichtet/?ref=detview1&rt=detview1&rb=1). I now would like to get the temperature of all of them simultaneously and write their temperature into a file on my computer (Linux, Win, Mac doesn't matter). What possibilities would I have? What costs do I have to expect? Is there any board with a USB-adapter?

Comment: We are electrical *engineering*, so we can talk about the details of building (and most probably programming) such a system. We don't advise on the buying of such a system.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, Building a test system from bought components is not an unusual task for an electrical engineer. We don't recommend specific products, but we can advise on what types of parts need to be bought and how to choose them.

Comment: If you have a budget over $2000 or so, then look for a scanning multimeter or data acquisition system. Keysight, Keithley, and others make such instruments with just this task in mind.

Comment: I'd be happy to recommend specific part numbers in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is very easy to solve.

You have two ways to choose from:

- UART to USB converter
- Real USB with HID or CDC class

Only thing you have to do is to send some data from temperature sensor (i think, using ADC converter). You can use FTDI UART <-> USB converters - and send data as normal UART signals.

Many uC's has built-in USB stack - some of PIC - also 8-bit (ex. PIC16F1459), AVR's (Atmega8U2), or 32-bit STM (like STM32F405).
USB is more complicated than UART, but you can make amazing things with it. Also - CDC USB class works as UART emulator without any additional chips.

But for this kind of operation - use UART to USB converter, if you want to do it fast.

Also - with Arduino you can do it in about 15 minutes - it has dedicated virtual Serial port.

But communication is simple here. There is another problem with this. PCB for this circuit will be big. Why? You have to find way to measure all 50 ADC channels. Only microcontrollers with many GPIO can do it without additional multiplexer IC. Another thing to do is to create some noise-preventing circuits, beacuse this amount of channel can generate it - and also - you need to prevent temperature-measurement channels from noise from microcontroller. Also to increase linearity and stability you have to do bridge excitation circuits - which will take area. If you want create 3 sensor PCB - it's very easy to do it. But 50 sensors... You have to imagine that.

What if you got small amount of ADC channels? Use analog multiplexers - but then you need more GPIO for drive multiplexer logic, and more place for new integrated circuits on your PCB. Remember - analog multiplexers aren't ideal - so one channel can affect another (you have this kind of informations in datasheet).

If you use 50 channels in your microcontroller remember about proper delay between conversion on various channels - beacuse if you change channel instantly, internal ADC capacitor will have some voltage, and this will falsify measurement value.

This problem sounds easy, but it's not as easy as we think.

Try first to do temperature meter with 4 channels.

Comment: I don't think collecting and logging 50 analog signals is particularly easy to solve.

Comment: You can do it very fast - for ex. if you have ADC that need about 5us for sample, 5us for convert and 5 us for delay between channels, you have about 750us to do all measurements. Also - for example - uC has 4 ADC channels. You must get about 50 samples. It's very easy to use some analog multiplexers, for example 4-bit. You have 4*16 channels if you use them (2^4=16). Only problem is that you need to increase place for components on PCB.

Comment: Yes, so now you have many analog multiplexers, and you need to control them.  You need to have excitation circuits for the thermistors, while paying attention to how that interacts with the analog switches (you may need 50 excitation circuits)!  You'll probably need to make a board and figure out how to cable up the fifty thermistors.  I think a talented undergrad early in an EE curriculum could probably get it done in two or three weeks.  Your answer only addresses one aspect of the approach to the solution.  If you lay out the whole answer, I'll remove the DV.

Comment: Hi @SławomirKozok ! Thanks for your extensive and well describing answer! Ok, I may follow your suggestion to try it with 4 channels first. Giving the [Arduino UNO R3](http://www.amazon.com/Arduino-UNO-board-DIP-ATmega328P/dp/B006H06TVG/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1425007552&sr=8-2&keywords=Arduino) a try would be a good start? Would I still need a UART to USB converter or could I plug them directly? I believe within Linux for instance I would access the data read from the NTC-Thermistor by accessing /dev/ttyX, right?

Comment: Arduino UNO will ge good for start. Arduino has built-in USB <-> UART converter. You only have to buy Arduino. I do not remember name of UART emulated by Arduino on Linux, but yeah, it will be somewhere under /dev/.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to buy yourself some DAQ (data acquisition) boards from a company such as National Instruments. For each DAQ, build a signal conditioning board to convert the thermistors to voltage output. The circuitry for these boards would be very simple - basically a voltage reference for the whole board, plus a single resistor and capacitor for each thermistor.

BUT. This has two drawbacks. First is speed. You would need to sample each temperature channel in sequence, rather than all at once. This is probably not a real problem - thermistors typically have time constants in the seconds range, so you're not likely to lose much accuracy by sequential sampling. The second is perhaps a bigger problem - cost. You can get 32 channels @ 12 bits per channel for ~$1500 per board, and you need 2 boards for 50 channels. If you want to risk eBay you may be able to get lower prices on used boards.

Alternatively, you can get one or more digital IO USB boards and roll your own. A 32-bit DIO board should set you back ~$100, and 32 bits should be more than enough to acquire 50 channels. Search on Digikey and you can get parallel-output 8-bit ADCs for less than $2, 12 bits for less than $10 (and depending on the temperature range you're looking at, and the temperature resolution you want, 12 bits may well be necessary - thermistors are very nonlinear). You would need to make pc boards for your signal conditioning and ADCs, and can make your own tradeoffs between number of ADCs and multiplexing. You might also need to learn digital multiplexing to select which ADC you want to read (if you use more than one), but that's something you need to learn anyways.

Comment: Hi @WhatRoughBeast! Thanks for your great answer! Regarding your suggestion on DAQ I had a little research and found 2 devices. Are they worth having a look at? [USB Based 24-Channel Digital I/O Module](http://www.amazon.com/USB-Based-24-Channel-Digital-Module/dp/B003DV6W9G/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1425008021&sr=1-1&keywords=DAQ) and [INPUT/OUTPUT DEVICE,USB,2.0 PORTABLE DIGITAL,24 LINES,12Mb](http://www.amazon.com/INPUT-OUTPUT-DEVICE-PORTABLE-DIGITAL/dp/B00R5CHGH6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1425008369&sr=8-1&keywords=National+Instruments). Would I still need an ADC for every NTC-Thermistor?

Comment: Either of those will work, but be aware that you may (possibly) want a high speed bus device. The question of how many ADCs you need depends on your requirements. If you absolutely must have simultaneous measurements, then yes, you should use one ADC per sensor. Otherwise, look up "analog multiplexer". These will allow a single ADC to acquire several (or many) sensor outputs. For the first configuration, you'll need some way, controlled by the 24 bits, to select which ADC you read, and step through the ADCs. Otherwise, you select the channel to go to the ADC(s), then read it or them...

Comment: In general, the analog multiplexer approach will be cheaper than the multiple ADC approach. It's all a question of what matters most to you: making tradeoffs between competing requirements is the heart of engineering